# Database schema suggestion for widget driven site

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema, logic

I am currently working on restructuring my site's database. As the schema I have now is not one of the best, I thought it would be useful to hear some suggestions from you.

To start off, my site actually consists of widgets. For each widget I need a table for `settings` (where each instance of the widget has its user defined settings), a table for `common` (shared items between instances of the same widget) and `userdata` (users' saved data within an instance of a widget).

Until now, I had the following schema, consisting of 2 databases:

- the first database, where I had all site-maintenance tables (e.g. users, widgets installed, logs, notifications, messages etc.) PLUS a table where I joined each widget instance to each user that instanciated it, having assigned a unique ID (so, I have the following columns: `user_id`, `widget_id` and `unique_id`).
- the second database, where I kept all widget-related data. That means, for each widget (unique by its `widget_id`) I had three tables: `[widget_id]_settings`, `[widget_id]_common` and `[widget_id]_userdata`. In each of these tables, each row held that `unique_id` of the users' widget. Actually here was all the users' data stored within a widget.

To give a short example of how my databases worked:

First database:

- In the `users` table I have `user_id = 1`
- In the `widgets` table I have `widget_id = 1`
- In the `users_widgets` table I have `user_id = 1, widget_id = 1, unique_id = 1`

Second database:

- In the `1_settings` I have `unique_id = 1, ...`, where ... represents the user's widget settings
- In the `1_common` I have several rows which represent shared data between instances of the same widget (so, no user specific data here)
- In the `1_userdata` I have `unique_id = 1, ...`, where ... represents the user's widget data. An important notice here is that this table may contain several rows with the same `unique_id` (e.g. For a tasks widget, a user can have several tasks for a widget instance)

Hope you understood in the rough my database schema.

Now, I want to develop a 'cleaner' schema, so it won't be necessary to have 2 databases and switch each time from one to another in my application. It would be also great if I found a way NOT to dinamically generate tables in the second database (1_settings, 2_settings, ... , n_settings).

I will greatly appreciate any effort in suggesting any better way of achieving this. Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT:**
Shall I have databases like MongoDB or CouchDB in my mind when restructurating my databases? I mean, for the second database, where it would be better if I didn't have a fixed schema.
Also, how would traditional SQL's and NoSQL's get along on the same site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible schema for the users_widgets table could be:

```
id | user_id | widget_id
```

You don't need the `unique_id` field in the `users_widgets` table, unless you want to hide the primary key for some reason. In fact, I would rename this table to something a little more memorable like `widget_instances`, and use `widget_instance_id` in the remaining tables of the second database.

One way to handle the second set of tables is by using a **metadata** style:

**widget_instance_settings**

```
id | widget_instance_id | key | value
```

This would include the userdata, because user_id is related to the widget_instance_id, unless you want to allow a user to create multiple instances of the same widget, and have the same data across all instances for some reason.

**widget_common_settings**

```
id | widget_id | key | value
```

This type of schema can be seen in packages like [Elgg](http://www.elgg.org/).

Comment: Another great suggestion from a great user! :) Your suggestions looks quite 'solid' and scalable. This way, I probably won't need the second database as I will integrate the 3 tables in my first database. My question is that, if I have 1000 widget instances, for example, each widget with 5 different settings - this means I will have in my `widget_instance_settings` 5000 rows. And this increases with every widget instance a user creates. Will MySQL be able to deal with such a large amount of data within one table?

Comment: And also, using the schema you mentioned, will it be easy for Cake (as I'm developing this project on this framework) to handle a specific widget instance consisting of 'n' rows within a database table? (where 'n' is the number of settings a widget can have). And I'm planning to share widgets (that is, copy all data from a widget instance of one user, to the instance of another user). Will this be easy to achieve? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Definitely. Just make sure you INDEX the `widget_instance_id` column, and maybe even the `key` column. There shouldn't be any problems using this schema with CakePHP.

Comment: Thanks. Also, shall I have NoSQL in my mind for storing user data? I mean, it could be helpful storing data in dynamic schemas. Are other pros and cons that could make me opt or not for NoSQL?

Comment: You could use NoSQL for the settings tables. But I can't say I have enough experience with NoSQL yet to give you a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the settings a widget class and widget instance could have? In this case these settings could be made columns of the widget_class table (for common settings) and widget_instance (for instance specific settings).
 
If you don't know them, then you could have a widget_class_settings table that has a many to one relation with the widget_class table and a widget_instance_settings that has a many to one relation to the widget_instance table. Between the widget_instance and the widget_class you could, again, have a many to one relation. The widget_instance could also have a foreign key in the users table, so that you know which user created a specific widget.

Comment: You mixed up a little bit the tables, perhaps I wasn't very clear in my explanations. A user can CREATE a widget (and upload it on my site) and a user can USE a widget. These are two different stories. I don't have problems with the first one, only with the second one. When a new widget is installed, 3 different tables are created in the second database (this is what happens now). Each of the 3 tables has a predefined schema, as for what the widget needs (while the tasks widget needs a `task_name` column, the notes widget needs a `note_content` column). So all column are predefined.

Comment: Now, when a user starts using a widget, we add a new row in the `users_widgets` table within the first database, containing a `unique_id`. Then, we add a new row in `[widget_id]_settings` in the second database, using that `unique_id`. The settings row is mandatory; each widget instance must be registered in the settings table. When a user adds something (e.g. a task), we create in the `[widget_id]_userdata` a row, also using the `unique_id`, with the task. The thing I wanted to know is how can I improve this system, thus not having two databases,from which one consisting of 'n' tables.Thanks!